# Automation of openldap installation

Tags: shell-script, ldap, deployment

In my group we often install ldap on new servers. We have two different configurations currently. A mirrored configuration and just a regular standalone configuration.

The installation process gets repetitive and is difficult for some team members to perform due to their lack of experience performing the install. Essentially it's a waste of time.

Do you have any suggestions on how to automate the process?

My current idea is to provide a zipped up directory with all the source packages necessary to install. It will also include an 'installation' script that will unzip and compile all source packages and proceed to install them and configure anything related to ldap and even prepopulate openldap with some base data.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you aren't using a package manager to install openldap? That would probably make it easier to do.

Another thing that comes to mind is [puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/) which is a tool designed to automate server configuration.

Comment: If he uses puppet, he will definitely want it to be packaged.

Comment: Well, we don't have an internet connection on some of the machines we're doing the installs on. 

Also, the package manager won't preload ldap with default data. I know it's something 'small' but I still think it's necessary.

Comment: I don't know how to install specific versions of a package either but I'm sure that's just a google away to figure out.

Comment: You don't need an internet connection. Most package managers allow to install packages also from the filesystem. Pre-populating the OpenLDAP DB can be done using [`slapadd`](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/dbtools.html). The LDIF used for `slapadd` can be generated using `slapcat` from an existing installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have new machine with fresh OS+LDAP setup make a image using CloneZilla and use it on the new machines. This will take less time and the Internet connection is not necessary.

Assume that your machines are connected in Internal Network.

Otherwise you can setup local repository using apt-cacher and make use of it to install the packages on local network